# Django CMS - Placeholder for edit mode

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Is there a placeholder that indicates if the page is in edit mode or not? Something like

`{% is_edit_mode %}`?

I couldn't find anything in [djangocms documentation](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.4.3/index.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in 3.0: {{ request.toolbar.edit_mode }}

Answer (score 2):

In django cms 3.8 it's now

```
{{ request.toolbar.edit_mode_active }}
```

See http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/toolbar.html#cms.toolbar.toolbar.CMSToolbar.edit_mode_active

Answer (score 0):

you can see it from `?edit` parameter in URL

Comment: This is not comprehensive enough.

Comment: @petr yea you are right, I already forgot what I meant :D but digi604 already helped well enough

Answer (score 0):

This works with 2.x

```
{% if 'edit' in request.GET %}
    {% placeholder content %}
{% endif %}
```